# Analytical solution to PDE exists?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have the following PDE:

$\delta_\epsilon(S(\epsilon)\phi(x,\epsilon))+\delta_x\phi(x,\epsilon) = -T(\epsilon)\phi(x,\epsilon)$

Deltas represent partial derivatives, for ease of notation. Does it have an analytical solution? Or at least a semi-analytical solution dependent on T and S? I tried to do separation of variables, but the $S(\epsilon)$ is throwing me off. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Write it as
$$
S\,\partial_\epsilon\phi+\partial_x\phi=-(S'+T)\phi.
$$
This is a first order linear equation that can be soved by the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).

Comment: And I'm assuming you arrived at this by just expanding the $\epsilon$ derivative with Chain Rule?

Comment: Not the chain rule but the product rule.

Comment: RIght. Thank you very much